# How do I make a textbox and button so it will fire a javascript method and not post?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I create a textbox and button in HTML so that when I click it, it will fire a javascript method with the value and output the result below the textbox/button?  And if you click again, it will continue to add new lines of output below the textbox/button?

Say I have the following function:

```
function double(number)
{
    return number * 2;
}
```

and I want a textbox and button so if I click the button three times, I will get this:

> Textbox Here (value of 2) - Button here
>   4
>   4
>   4

How is this done?  Do I use a form with two input tags?  Or use button tag?  How do I make it keep outputing below the textbox/button?

I'm sorry if this question is difficult to read, my english isn't very good.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function calculate() {
   var number = parseInt(document.getElementById('Number').value);
   document.getElementById('Result').innerHTML += double(number) + '<br/>';
}

function double(number) {
   return number * 2;
}

</script>

<input type="text" id="Number"/>
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate();"/>
<div id="Result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery - you could do:

```
$('#form_id').submit(function(e){
  $('#output_element').append(double_func(parseInt($('#text').val(), 10))); // I changed the name of your function because 'double' is reserved...
  return false;  // This stops the form from submitting.
});
```

Comment: +1 for picking up on the reserved word use. and -1 for answering with: use jQuery. It was a simple question and doesn't need a large framework to solve it.

Comment: If this was his entire application, then you would probably be correct. I didn't tell him he _should_ use jQuery, I merely offered that solution by saying that he _could_ do it. It's pretty clear from his post that he probably wont be able to handle browser quirks, etc. He actually sounds like the perfect candidate for the kind of abstraction and ease of use that jQuery offers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function javaScriptFunction(){
  documet.getElementById("output").html += "<br>"+document.getElementById("textbox").value*2;
}
</script>

<form onsubmit="javaScriptFunction(); return false;">
<input type="text" id="textbox" />
<p id="output">

</p>
<input type="submit" value="Click Me!" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help!

**NOTE: `number.match(/^\d+$/ )` confirms the value should be numeric.**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function calulation() {
            var number = document.forms[0].number.value;
            if( number.match(/^\d+$/ ) )
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += double(number) + "<br/>";
            else
                alert("Only numeric allowed");
        }

        function double(number) {   return number * 2;}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form onsubmit="calulation();return false;">
        <input id="number" type="text"/><input type="submit" value="calculate" />
    </form>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```